# Using function to turn every even letter Ipper and every odd letter lower

Tags: python

I created a function that turns every odd letter into lower case and every even letter to upper case but it does not what to work.I want it to return the string where all evens are lower and odds are upper

```
def myfunc(a):
b = a.split()
c = 1
for letter in b:
    if c%2==0:
        return letter.upper
    else:
        return letter.lower
    c=c+1

return b
```

Comment: What does *"it does not what to work"* mean? Be specific.

Comment: Your indentation isn't correct

Comment: You can only return once from a function. You have to build the output inside your function, and return it once at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Any function will acknowledge only one return call. Whichever return it encounters first, will give the return value of function. Please try this.

```
def myfunc(a):
  b = list(a)
  for index, letter in enumerate(b):
    if index % 2 == 0:
      b[index] = letter.upper()
    else:
      b[index] = letter.lower()
  return "".join(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a one liner

```py
def func(a):
    return "".join([c.lower() if i%2 else c.upper() for i,c in enumerate(a)])
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `return` inside a function when some condition is met and once condition is met data preceding return is given back. so in your case either you should update the `b` or create a new list and add data to it.

Below is a sample code implementation of your code

```
# your code goes here
def myfunc(a):
    b = list(a)
    for index, letter in enumerate(b):
        if index%2:
            b[index] = letter.lower()
        else:
            b[index] = letter.upper()

    return ''.join(b)

print(myfunc("hello world")) # output HeLlO WoRlD
```

or

```
def myfunc(a):
        b = list(a)
        return ''.join([(value.lower() if index%2 else value.upper())  for index, value in enumerate(b)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
def myfunc(myString):
    word = []
    while a:
        for i in range(len(myString)):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                word.append(myString[i].upper())
            else:
                word.append(myString[i].lower())
        break
    return ''.join(word)
```